How to get the feature names from a OneHotEncoder embedded in a ColumnTransformer?
How can I get the feature names from a OneHotEncoder embedded in a ColumnTransformer?
The following piece of code:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1],[2]], columns = ['C'])
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output = False)
transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', ohe, ['C'])])
transformer.fit_transform(df)
ohe.get_feature_names_out()

results in the following error message:
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-46f41a3cf71a> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', ohe, ['C'])])
      9 transformer.fit_transform(df)
---> 10 ohe.get_feature_names_out()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
   1388 
   1389     if not fitted:
-> 1390         raise NotFittedError(msg % {"name": type(estimator).__name__})
   1391 
   1392 

NotFittedError: This OneHotEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

Why?

You need to get the feature names via the named_transformers_ attribute because OneHotEncoder is one in a list of transformers. Because it's named 'encoder', the following returns the feature names of one-hot-encoding:
transformer.named_transformers_['encoder'].get_feature_names_out()

# array(['encoder__C_1', 'encoder__C_2'], dtype=object)

Another way is via get_feature_names_out of the ColumnTransformer object. Because feature names are of the pattern, <transformer name>__<feature name>, we can filter for the relevant names using the 'encoder' prefix:
[x for x in transformer.get_feature_names_out() if x.startswith('encoder')]

# ['encoder__C_1', 'encoder__C_2']

